# Consistency level in Datastax Object Mapping API

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Maybe I overlooked it, but I can't find a way to specify consistency level in [Datastax Object Mapping API](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/objectMappingApi.html) for Java.

I understand that it is CQL3 based and in CQL, you can specify consistency by USING CONSISTENCY clause. But in Object Mapping API you wouldn't directly deal with the queries. So how would you specify the consistency when persisting or retrieving objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at the code in GitHub. There is indeed a way to set read and write consistency levels. You can specify the consistency levels using @Table annotation.

```
@Table (keyspace="XXX", name="riders", readConsistency="QUORUM", writeConsistency="QUORUM")
```

http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Table.html#readConsistency()

Answer (score 1):

We also had same problem, because we used `save()` method of `Mapper` class. You can use `saveQuery()` method which is creating `Statement` out of your mapped class. Here is example:

```
final MappingManager mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
Mapper<MyMappedClass> myMapper = mappingManager.mapper(MyMappedClass.class);
MyMappedClass myMappedInstance = new MyMappedClass(property1, propert2);
session.execute(myMapper.saveQuery(myMappedInstance).setConsistencyLevel(QUORUM));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish the api had a simpler way of specifying the consistency level.

Comment: Yeah me too since now session is wrapped inside and you do not need to think about it (just do save) but this way you are back to prepared statements and must do everything again

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: That is ok if you always read and write with same consistency to table. We are tuning consistency for different cases per request and configure it from properties file so this way plays good for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of documentation depending on what exactly are you doing. Please check the following pages:

- http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/class-use/ConsistencyLevel.html
- http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html

Perhaps one of them will be helpful for your specific case.